# start first Rails site localhost or remote host?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have PHP5 skills and would now like to start learning Rails. I have a Baby plan with Hostgator, and I have started working through some guides to get Refinery setup. My concern is that I am doing things the slow and stupid way. Can anyone suggest whether I would be better off if I created my Rails RefineryCMS site on my local machine then migrated to my remote host, or would this be more of a mess for a new guy? Trying to get my portfolio site live as soon as reasonable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would run it locally on localhost so you can test it out while developing. Once its ready you can deploy to your remote host.

Answer (score 0):

To develop a new app you should always start it locally, since you are just starting is better if you try to understand rails before start using a CMS.

Hostgator support for rails sucks, but http://www.heroku.com/ is the best server ever and it is free for small stuff.

Comment: Oh awesome, I think I seen Heroku before a friend showed me a while back but I forgot to try it. Definitely a good idea, great. you guys are awesome I appreciate the help!